# Is it possible to disable a scheduled task from the command line in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, scheduled-task

On my Windows 7 machine I can run something like:

```
schtasks.exe /Change /TN "MyTaskName" /Disable
```

But /Disable doesn't seem to be available in Windows XP - is there any way of disabling it from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `/disable` switch is only a [feature of Vista/7/2008R2/2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766529.aspx).

You can simply rename the task `.job` file to "disable" it.

```
schtasks /Create /SC HOURLY /TN "TEST TASK" /TR notepad
schtasks

TaskName                             Next Run Time            Status
==================================== ======================== ===============
TEST TASK                            09:45:00, 7/26/2010

move "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\TEST TASK.job" "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\TEST TASK.bak"
schtasks
INFO: There are no scheduled tasks present in the system.
```

In order to "enable" the task rename the `.bak` file to `.job`:

```
schtasks
INFO: There are no scheduled tasks present in the system.

move "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\TEST TASK.bak" "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\TEST TASK.job"
schtasks

TaskName                             Next Run Time            Status
==================================== ======================== ===============
TEST TASK                            09:45:00, 7/26/2010
```

Comment: Good idea. However I'd really like it to actually appear as disabled in Task scheduler, so I can enable it again at some point in the future. Normally you could just set it to "Run Once" and set a specific time, but this particular script we need to run on login, and then disable itself.

Comment: @John: Updated my answer to show "enabling" example.  Barring that option, you can copy `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe` binary from a 2003+ install. Place this binary on the XP machine and call it using its explicit path. I have just successfully tested disabling a task created with the XP `schtasks` using the 2003 `schtasks`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - I'm going to use the Win2003 workaround as this fits our situation better. But the renaming idea may also come in handy at some point too

Answer (score 2):

In order to acheive the run-once behaviour, you could always just code a 'wrapper' bat script that checks for a lock file.

Create the lock file on first run, and every there after the wrapper script will just exit if it finds the lock file:

```
if exist Lock.file goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run this code:

```
SCHTASKS /Change /TN "\yourFolder\yourTask" /Disable
```